# What, in Haskell, does an underscore preceding a variable mean?

Tags: haskell

I was browsing the source of Data.Foldable, where I came accross `Endo #. f`, and upon clicking this link, was confronted with:

```
(#.) _f = coerce
```

Now, first, I don't know what `coerce` and the before-that mentioned `Coercible` is, however, it baffles me more what the `_f` could mean. I have searched "Haskell underscore before variable" and similar and have only found discussions about the `_` pattern matching syntax.

Comment: You can find this list useful: https://github.com/takenobu-hs/haskell-symbol-search-cheatsheet

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the Haskell spec, it is just another possible name for a variable. But the truth is a bit longer, because most Haskell developers write code specifically for GHC, and this is one of those times.

GHC has lots of helpful warnings; one is to warn you when you write a pattern that binds a variable that isn't used in the body of the function. It's pretty handy, and has caught a couple bugs of mine. However, it has a knock-on effect: if you write a function that uses some of the variables only in one clause or the other, you get a warning. For example, here is a very natural definition of `foldr` on lists:

```
 foldr f z [] = z
 foldr f z (x:xs) = x `f` foldr f z xs
```

Oops! We didn't use `f` in the first clause, and we'll get a warning. Okay, so it's easy enough to fix:

```
foldr _ z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = x `f` foldr f z xs
```

Unfortunately now we've lost the information about what that first variable's role in the code is supposed to be. In this case, `foldr` is so familiar that it's no big loss, but in unfamiliar codebases with functions that take a lot of arguments, it can be nice to know what data is ignored by each "hole". So GHC adds a special rule: the warning about unused variables doesn't warn you about variable names that start with `_` -- by analogy to the `_` pattern that it also doesn't warn you about. So now I can write:

```
foldr _f z [] = z
foldr  f z (x:xs) = x `f` foldr f z xs
```

Now I get the best of both worlds: I get a nice warning if I forget to use a variable I bound, and I can still give the reader information about the meaning of the holes in patterns that I don't need for the current clause. (As a side note, I'd love an additional warning that reported if I *do* mistakenly use a variable starting with `_`, but I don't think it exists at the moment! It sounds stupid ("just don't type `_` in a function body"), but I've found my editor's tab-completion occasionally inserting them for me, and it would be easy not to notice if you were coding quickly.)

Comment: To me it looks like the single underscore name has something more than names starting with underscore. The former can be used more than once in a single match without triggering the _Conflicting definitions for ‘\_’_ error; furthermore, it cannot be used in the rhs of `=`.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Correct, a single underscore is special: it is not a valid variable name at all, in fact! It *is* a pattern, which matches anything, and binds no names. (And this pattern is even mentioned off-hand in the answer.)

Comment: Ok, it was not apparent to me from your (nonetheless excellent) answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a convention to mark an unused variable. As you see, `_f` isn't used in the definition of `#.`, so it is marked with the underscore.

Comment: It's a tad bit more than human convention though  - GHC won't give unused variable warnings for underscore-prefixed variables.